# Near Real Time Algorithm For Approximating Fundamental Frequency

Tags: fft, wavelet, autocorrelation, fundamental-frequency

I'd like to analyse the notes being played on a cello C2(65.4Hz) to C6(1046.5Hz) recorded on a PC and thus a likely sampling rate of 44.1kHz. If I can get that to behave then I'd like to be able to deal with the top note of a violin A7(3520Hz).

I understand that the frequency response of most microphones rolls off at 100Hz or higher and so I'll need to deal with a missing or weak fundamental frequency.

For fine resolution, I'll most likely use an autocorrelation function using the whole signal i.e. not downsampled.

But rather than attempt to apply the function across the whole range of the cello I'd like to calculate an approximation of the fundamental frequency and use that as a starting point for the ACF. With the proviso that the combination of Approximation + ACF isn't longer than just a wider ranged ACF.

This leads to the following questions.

Which algorithm should I try to use for the initial approximation of the fundamental frequency?

How far should I downsample, understanding that Nyquist sets an absolute maximum? But I suspect getting too close to that value will cause problems.

Sample file with open strings. [CelloADGC](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10QONQthr9k4uf4FcNOOgegzkvVd3G3NC/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Any chance you can link a sample example file that you would like to be able to do this on?  That will help clarify duration of the notes and temporal changes if any, if there are multiple notes, signal to noise ratios etc...

Comment: @DanBoschen I've added a link to a sample file with open strings being played on a somewhat tuned cello.

Comment: @DanBoschen Eventually I will want to look at double stops, two strings being played at once. I'm also wondering about when and how to apply filtering. But for now I'm interested in how to get F0 for a single string quickly and at relatively low processing cost.